# How to Add a datepicker in excel that works when sending it to others

Tags: excel, datepicker

Ok. I have used the datepicker ActiveX with Excel 2007 a lot of times. On my computer it works
very well. BUT when I sendt the excel sheet to others, a lot of them experience problems with the
datepicker. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: duplicate of [Formatting MM/DD/YYYY dates in textbox in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012206/formatting-mm-dd-yyyy-dates-in-textbox-in-vba). The other question is quite different, but the [answer by @Siddarth Rout](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12013961/14420) is correct for this one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build the entire module into the Excel workbook. [How-to](http://www.yogeshguptaonline.com/2010/01/excel-macros-excel-date-picker.html)