# Adding DateTimePicker to Userform

Tags: vba, excel

How can I add a DateTimePicker to a User Form using VBA code.

Similar to adding a Label -

```
Dim TempForm As Object
Dim NewLabel as MSForms.Label

 Set NewLabel = TempForm.Designer.Controls.Add("Forms.label.1")
```

Comment: Vikram, I wouldn't recommend using the DateTimePicker as you cannot freely distribute the control. The enduser might not have the OCX registered. If you are interested in an alternative then have a look at my reply for showing dates in a userform in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012206/formatting-mm-dd-yyyy-dates-in-textbox-in-vba

Comment: Thanks Siddharth ...looks nice !!

Comment: Hi Siddharth , in the component which you had shared , the QueryClose event is not being executed ,and I see many temp worksheets created in my project. Also I removed the textbox , OK and Cancel buttons from the form as I dont need them  . And included Unload Me in every other button click event.Any idea why this is happening ?

Comment: I changed xlSheetVeryHidden to xlSheetHidden and ws.Delete works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I have got the answer from this question in the sidharth

[Formatting MM/DD/YYYY dates in textbox in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012206/formatting-mm-dd-yyyy-dates-in-textbox-in-vba)