# datepicker that works for Excel 2010/2007/2003

Tags: excel, vba, datepicker

I need a datepicker in VBA for Excel.

I had run into this issue because Excel 2010 64 bit does not have a datepicker, which worked fine in Excel 2007/2003.

I am looking for a free control which can be used for commercial purposes.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012206/formatting-mm-dd-yyyy-dates-in-textbox-in-vba & http://fontstuff.com/vba/vbatut07.htm

Comment: no this is like a validation control.. i am looking for something if you click on a control and a calender pops up and you select a date.. thanks though

Comment: Siddharth Rout posted one in this SO discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012206/formatting-mm-dd-yyyy-dates-in-textbox-in-vba

Answer (score 2):

We have created a VBA solution, what fully compatible with the old MSCAL.OCX, but you need no ActicveX install to use it:

https://sites.google.com/site/e90e50/calendar-control-class

It works in all Excel (Access, etc.) versions too.  :)

Best Regards, 
Axelock

Answer (score 1):

I have come across this issue many times in the past and the only sure fire way to circumvent it is to make a custom calendar control in VBA

Here is the one I use created by a colleague of mine back in 2009 http://goo.gl/hyhIh

It does the job very well, I have adapted my own one in several MS Access projects in the past feel free to use for your own purposes

Comment: That's nice too! :)