# sql source for a vba userform

Tags: sql, vba

I am struggling to establish a SQL connection/source for a VBA ListBox userform. I have been able to import the correct sql table to an excel sheet (from the code below) but all my attempts so far to load the same data as a source for the listbox have failed. The code below was given to me my a colleague and adapted to our db.

```
Sub SQL_VBA()

Dim sConn As String
Dim oQt As QueryTable
Dim sSql As String

'defining the connection string

sConn = "ODBC;DSN=RISK_DB;UID=;PWD=;"
sConn = sConn & "WSID=;DATABASE=RISK_DB"

sSql = str_SQLText

Set oQt = Sheet1.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=sConn, Destination:=Sheet1.Range("A1"), Sql:=sSql)

With oQt
.Name = "Query from"
.FieldNames = True '' This returns the headers of the tables you need
.RowNumbers = False
.PreserveFormatting = True
.RefreshOnFileOpen = False '' Dont want to refresh file each time it opens
.BackgroundQuery = False
.RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
.SavePassword = False
.SaveData = True
.AdjustColumnWidth = True
.RefreshPeriod = 0
.PreserveColumnInfo = True
.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=True

End With

End Sub
```

Has anyone experience with loading SQL tables as data sources for userforms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14089376/populating-a-listbox-with-recordset-and-comparing-dates) will answer your question.

If you have any more questions, just leave a comment.