# How to install mscomct2.ocx file from .cab file (Excel User Form and VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel spreadsheet with a user form that uses the calendar control.  It works fine on my machine, but others can't use it because they are missing the mscomct2.ocx file.  I found where to download it (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/297381), but it comes down as a cab file, and I'm not sure how to tell others to use that file.  My internet searches point to a variety of solutions from copying it to the system32 file to registering it using regsrv32.  I was hoping somebody here could give me layman's instructions, as I hate to ask these other users to try five different things.

Comment: An Alternative which will not require any user to install anything... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012206/formatting-mm-dd-yyyy-dates-in-textbox-in-vba/12013961#12013961

Comment: Wow, that is awesome!  Thanks.  If you put that as an answer, I will quickly accept it.  Thanks again!

Comment: That's Ok :) It's no point posting the same answer again :)

Comment: The path you specified is no longer allowed for public use. Could you provide me with this cab?

Comment: @NoChance The .cab file can be obtained using [Internet Archive](http://www.archive.org): 1.) [original link using archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20120808064855/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/297381)
2.) [The .cab file from the archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20120113035142/http://activex.microsoft.com/controls/vb6/MSComCt2.cab)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're correct that this is really painful to hand out to others, but if you have to, this is how you do it.

1. Just extract the .ocx file from the .cab file (it is similar to a zip)
2. Copy to the system folder (*c:\windows\sysWOW64* for 64 bit systems and *c:\windows\system32* for 32 bit)
3. Use regsvr32 through the command prompt to register the file (e.g. "*regsvr32 c:\windows\sysWOW64\mscomct2.ocx*")

*References*

- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sbappdev/thread/91cf3127-70fe-4726-8a27-31b8964430c5/
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cabinet_(file_format)

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly.  One note to anybody else who finds this--I learned I had to run the command prompt as an administrator (from Start menu, type "cmd", then right click the cmd.exe file and choose "Run as Administrator").