# Find/Remove all uses of VBA reference

Tags: vba, excel

I have an old spreadsheet that used date picker from MSCOMCT2.OCX. Then the computer I used it on died. Unfortunately the [Microsoft KB article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/297381) that has the download for MSCOMCT2.OCX only has a dead link.

My only recourse is to remove the reference to MSCOMCT2.OCX and use other methods to pick the date. I have removed the object from the spreadsheet and all references I can find to it in the code, but when I go to remove it I get an error message stating that the "Can't remove control or reference, in use"

How can I find where it is still being referenced?

Comment: Can you find a download of the MSCOMCT2.OCX file, then install and register it? Alternatively, try running the [VBA Code Cleaner](http://www.appspro.com/Utilities/CodeCleaner.htm) which often helps me with obscure issues like this.

Comment: Do you have any forms?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I do not

Comment: @PeterT I could not find a copy on the day that I posted this, I was however finally able to find one over the weekend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the solution seem to be that you have to have to fix the broken link before you remove it. I finally found a [copy of the .cab file at archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20141012205821/http://activex.microsoft.com/controls/vb6/mscomct2.cab). Once I installed it following [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15816646/1111886) I was able to open my file and remove the reference without issue.