# "object not available on this machine" on another machine running the same version of excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have written some VBA code which works fine on my machine and sent it to someone for testing. When they attempt to run the code on their machine they get an error message stating: "Could not load some objects because they are not available on this machine."

Some research has revealed the likely issue is the fact that I am using a **Date Picker** object in a userform, which supposedly doesn't work on all versions of excel. However this person is running excel 2010 32 bit just like me, so I don't understand why it wouldn't work.

Is there anything I can do to ensure my code will run on any machine running excel 2010 32 bit? Or do I have to revert to using textboxes D:

thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: Quoting response from @bonCodigo to similar question: "Date picker is not a standard control that comes with office package. So developers encountered issues like missing date picker controls when application deployed in some other machiens/versions of office. In order to use it you have to activate the reference to the .dll, .ocx file that contains it." https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13409653/how-to-add-date-picker-to-vba-userform

Comment: Might be worth asking the 'other person' to run an install/repair on their Office suite to check something hasn't become corrupt/deleted.

Comment: Thanks guys, would love to know if there was a way around this problem if I couldn't access the users PC though.

Comment: The "proper" way of doing it without access to the user's PC would be to build an MSI package. There are several guides for that out there and perhaps not in scope for SO. Having that said - it is not easier, but you will move the tough job from the receiver to yourself.