# DatePicker in an Excel UserForm - Outlook controls?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I've just tried to add an `OlkDateControl` to my **Excel** VBA UserForm but it tells me it can't load the control.

I had the control in my `Toolbox` already, and I'm pretty sure I've used it before but can't figure out how.

I've made sure this new workbook has `Outlook 16.0 Object Library` in the references

From an MS [VBA API guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.olkdatecontrol?):

> You can only add this control to a form region in an Outlook form using the forms designer; you cannot add this control to a Visual Basic UserForm object in the Visual Basic Editor.

I don't really know what this means - What is a form region? Can I create an Outlook form in Excel?

I tried creating it at run time:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim x As New OlkDateControl
    x.Value = "01/01/2021"
End Sub
```

Which runs fine but there's no sort of `x.Show` or way to show the control on the UserForm.

I also tried adding it to the UserForm

```
Dim x As New OlkDateControl
Set x = UserForm1.Controls.Add("OlkDateControl")
```

Any ideas?

(Or a good DatePicker alternative would also be great!)

Comment: Check out [How can I create a calendar input in VBA Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54650417/how-can-i-create-a-calendar-input-in-vba-excel) which has a nice pure VBA solution for date picking.

Comment: Ha I was hoping to use something that exists already on my laptop but I guess copy and pasting a whole bunch of stuff will do!

Comment: well there exists the datepicker from the  MSCOMCT2 see [How to Add Date Picker To VBA UserForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13409653/how-to-add-date-picker-to-vba-userform) but it is a pain in the a…

Answer (score 1):

I was annoyed to search for controls, install libraries or manage class modules.
Therefore I have programmed my own DatePicker, which only needs a single userform.
Just importing the frmWMDatePicker.frm (and its .frx of course) a function frmWMDatePicker.GetDate is provided which will open a userform to pick a date.

I provide my frmWMDatePicker at https://1drv.ms/f/s!AtjCbB-8TbkNgogTYGtFivQhi_kipQ
There's also an Excel workbook for testing and description.

Comment: Please read [answer] and [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really "good answers"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/248627) We expect answers to be useful on their own, even if all links break.