# This question seems stupid but is that a calader form that i may include in my vba form? thx

Tags: excel, vba, datepicker, office365, office-2013

Seems there was such a function in microsoft office 2013 32-bit version(Microsoft Date and Time Picker Control 6.0 (SP6)), but it seems that we cannot find it in office 365 now, is there an other alternative?

idk i scroll the whole addtional tools. Is it a must i did the form from scratch which is time consuming>_<?

Comment: Does [How can I create a calendar input in VBA Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54650417/how-can-i-create-a-calendar-input-in-vba-excel) solve your issue :)

Comment: See [Use a Calendar control or Date Picker to fill in dates](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s8/win003.htm).

Comment: Also take a look at the similar post [How to Add Date Picker To VBA UserForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13409653/how-to-add-date-picker-to-vba-userform)