# Importing Excel Data into MySQL

Tags: mysql, excel, csv

I have an enormous amount of data in an Excel Spreadsheet, one of the columns being **Date** in format **yyyy-mm-dd**. To transfer it to MySQL, I save the excel sheet as .csv and then import into PHPMyAdmin. Everything works fine, the only trouble is that upon importing, the date column in the database just appears as **0000-00-00**. Why is that happening?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using excel dates for importing into phpmyadmin sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13481119/using-excel-dates-for-importing-into-phpmyadmin-sql)

Comment: If you right click and open csv in text editor (not Excel), is dates in `YYYY-MM-DD`?

Comment: @Parfait it is fixed, I changed the values, and imported the csv file again, just that replacing table data with file doesn't simply work, it appends to the old data. So I dropped the table and re-imported it. It worked fine