# Excel Date Format changed after running code

Tags: vba, date

When i am running this code it changes the date format from `dd:mm:yy` to `mm:dd:yy`.

please give me some tips for this. Although it gets my job done how to keep the date format as it is?

```
Sub copyAllselectedWbtoSheets()
Set destWB = ActiveWorkbook
Dim DestCell As Range
FileNames = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
        filefilter:="Excel Files (*.csv*),*.csv*", _
        Title:="Select the workbooks to load.", MultiSelect:=True)
If IsArray(FileNames) = False Then
    If FileNames = False Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If
For N = LBound(FileNames) To UBound(FileNames)
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=FileNames(N), ReadOnly:=True)
    With wb
      .Sheets(1).Copy After:=destWB.Sheets(destWB.Sheets.Count)
      ActiveSheet.Name = Replace(wb.Name, ".csv", "ABC") 'Name sheet
      .Close True
    End With
Next N
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

- [Excel can get influenced by your system date/time settings.](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1694-how-excel-stores-date-and-time-values/)
- And what can the regional setting do to you using Excel? [How to Format VBA TextBox To Long Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13420691/how-to-format-vba-textbox-to-long-date/13421587#13421587).

So if you haven't read these posts simply do a `date formatting`. But this is temporary. You stil have to do the above regional setting changes if you need to have once for all solution.

`Format(yourdate, "dd:mm:yy")`

Comment: my regional settings are set as dd-mm-yyyy still its doing against the system's settings.