# Assign input of pop up window to a cell in excel

Tags: excel, popup, vba

I need a pop up imput box that asks for a long date ex Friday, April 24, 2013 then adds the date to cell I2.

I Googled looking for something like this and found

```
Public Function AskForResult() As String
    Dim strUserResponse As String

    strUserResponse = InputBox("Please Enter a Long Date")

End Function
```

But I can't figure out how to assign the input to the cell I2.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to use an inputbox and cater to lot of troubles? May I suggest a better [ALTERNATIVE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012206/formatting-mm-dd-yyyy-dates-in-textbox-in-vba/12013961#12013961)

Comment: Hello Siddharth Rout, I am trying to use the alternitve method "Userform1.frm and Userform1.frx" but not shure how to assign input to a cell. Thanks

Comment: Check out the `CommandButton53_Click` code. You can use 'Range("A`").value = TextBox1.Text`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add this line after your InputBox line:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 9).Value = strUserResponse
```

the 2, 9 is the cell reference for I2 - row 2, column 9.