# Restricting Date Picker Calender Control in Excel 2013 to just one column and total row

Tags: excel, datepicker, vba

i am working on Office 2013 x64 and the problem i faced was date picker. i searched the net and stackoverflow too and came across
[Calender Control](https://sites.google.com/site/e90e50/calendar-control-class)!
 i used the macro using vba provided by them in version 5 and it works in whole worksheet where i applied the macro, but my objective is to use this macro in only one column.Here are the lines

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

'If IsDate(Target.Cells(1, 1).Value) Then
    Set DatePickerForm.Target = Target.Cells(1, 1)
    DatePickerForm.Show vbModal
    Cancel = True
'End If

End Sub
```

i am finding a way to restrict macro to just one column but can't find success with code **I want to use this date picker tool in only A columns and A rows** so please help me, you can download xlsm file here which is a date control macro 
[Download .xlsm file](https://sites.google.com/site/e90e50/calendar-control-class/Calendar_Class_v1.1.0.xlsm?attredirects=0&d=1)!

Comment: have you tried something like: `If Target.Row = 1 and Target.Column = 1 Then...Show the data picker...`?

Comment: Why do you need complicated code (calendar control class) for such a simple thing ;) You might want to see [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012206/formatting-mm-dd-yyyy-dates-in-textbox-in-vba/12013961#12013961)

Comment: @KazJaw Yup i tried but excel stop responding whenever i double click..thanks

Comment: @SiddharthRout : thanks i am working with it..will see now