# Excel VBA for chart

Tags: excel, vba

I have two sheets in a workbook. 1st sheet name is “summary” and another is “target”.
I have chart in summary tab. I want to set the source data for that chart  to target tab that contains date. Ex(11/01/2013 – 11/30/2013).
Everyday I want to change the chart date for corresponding date. So I tried in excel vba as below:

```
sheets("Summary ").Select
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 3").Activate
ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
Sheets("Target").Select
a = InputBox("enter the date - format(mm/dd/yyyy)")

Set findrow = Range("a:a").Find(what:=a, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Rows

findrownumber = findrow.Row

ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = "='Target Chart'!R4C78:R" & findrownumber & "C78"
End sub
```

While I am trying to enter source data value in formula it shows error.

Please help me.

Comment: Well, what error does it show?

Answer (score 1):

This is the code that I tried and it works. I might have switched the names of the sheet while creating this example but you can change that in the code :)

Let's say the Summary Tab looks like this

[image]

And your Chart in `Target` Sheet looks like this at the moment. The source data is set to `=Summary!$A$1:$A$6`

[image]

Now Try this code

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim wsSum As Worksheet, wsTgt As Worksheet
    Dim objChart As ChartObject, chrt As Chart
    Dim sDate
    Dim findrow As Long
    Dim aCell As Range

    '~~> Accept the date
    sDate = InputBox("enter the date - format(mm/dd/yyyy)")

    '~~> Check if user entered something
    If sDate <> "" Then
        '~~> Set your respective worksheets
        Set wsSum = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary")
        Set wsTgt = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Target")

        '~~> Find the date in the cell
        With wsSum
            For Each aCell In .Columns(1).Cells
                If Format(aCell.Value, "mm/dd/yyyy") = sDate Then
                    '~~> Get the row number
                    findrow = aCell.Row
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next aCell
        End With

        '~~> Update the chart
        With wsTgt
            Set objChart = .ChartObjects("Chart 1")
            Set chrt = objChart.Chart

            chrt.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "='Summary'!R4C1:R" & findrow & "C1"
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

When you run the code, in the Inputbox, set the date as "01/11/2013"

[image]

And this is the output which you will get with source data set as `=Summary!$A$4:$A$11`

[image]

**IMPORTANT**: I wouldn't recommend using Inputbox for capturing a date. You might want to use [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012206/formatting-mm-dd-yyyy-dates-in-textbox-in-vba/12013961#12013961)