# Excel VBA - multiple Date Pickers on same sheet

Tags: vba, excel, datepicker

In my current project I'm in need of having two date pickers inserted from the developer tab.  One for the start date and the other for the end date.  For some reason whenever I add the 2nd date picker and go out of design mode and choose date on the 1st date picker, the 2nd one goes grey and becomes totally un usable. any one out there know why I can't have two date pickers on the same sheet of my workbook?

Comment: Why use a control which might not be available on another machine? You might want to see [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012206/formatting-mm-dd-yyyy-dates-in-textbox-in-vba/12013961#12013961) instead which can be called from a button on a worksheet?