# Excel: Enter dates in specific column

Tags: vba, excel

My requirement is:

I want to enter date from 1st Jan to 31st Jan in columns E5 to AI5. Currently using the below code which is not working.

Secondly year i m taking as user input which should change every time.

```
Sub LoopA()
    Call Using_InputBox_Method
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim PH As Integer
    i = 5
    For j = 5 To 35
               Cells(i, j).Value = "=Date(E1,1,j)"
    Next j


End Sub

    Public Function Using_InputBox_Method() As Integer


      Dim Response As Integer

  ' Run the Input Box.
  Response = Application.InputBox("Enter a Year.", _
     "Number Entry", , 250, 75, "", , 1)

  ' Check to see if Cancel was pressed.
  If Response <> False Then

     ' If not, write the number to the first cell in the first sheet.
     Worksheets(1).Range("E1").Value = Response

  End If

   Using_InputBox_Method = Response

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

**A)**

Anything within `"` will be considered as a `String`. So `"=Date(E1,1,j)"` is just a string. What you want, I guess is

```
"=Date(E1,1," & j & ")"
```

**B)**

`For j = 5 To 35`

Are you sure you want to go up till 35? The max you can have in any month is 31 :)

Syntax of `=Date()` is `DATE(year,month,day)`

Also you would need an additional check here to see if it is a valid date. For example 30th Feb will give you an error.

**C)**

`InputBox` should be avoided to accept dates. It can generate errors. You may want to use [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012206/formatting-mm-dd-yyyy-dates-in-textbox-in-vba/12013961#12013961). If you still want to use `InputBox` then you will have to do validations to ensure that there are no errors.

**D)**

Regarding, the `Year` changing automatically, You will have to increment the Year in Column E once the user automatically enters the date.

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim Yr As Long, i As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Yr = Application.InputBox("Enter a Year.", _
     "Number Entry", , 250, 75, "", , 1)

    '~~> Set it to whatever Year Range you want
    If Yr < 1900 Or Yr > 9999 Then
        MsgBox "Incorrect Year"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With ws
        .Range("E1").Value = Yr

        For i = 5 To 35
            .Cells(5, i).Formula = "=Date(E1,1," & (i - 4) & ")"
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```