# Cancel button in inputbox no change of value in excel cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am running an VBA  and I have problem with cancel button, I want no change of value in cell if cancel button pressed or escape button. How to proceed?

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Sheets("Start").Range("B1").Value = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Insert Date", Type:=1)
    Cancel = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Another way to accept dates [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012206/formatting-mm-dd-yyyy-dates-in-textbox-in-vba/12013961#12013961)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim inpt
    inpt = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Insert Date", Type:=1)
    If CStr(inpt) <> "False" Then Sheets("Start").Range("B1").Value = inpt
End Sub
```

the reason why I use `CStr(inpt) <> "False"` instead `inpt <> False` or just `If inpt Then` because user can enter `0` (it's valid input for inputbox with `Type:=1`)

Comment: Had missed this response, but still think is better to run with a numeric variable given a date is required rather than a variant

Comment: yeah, agree, +1 to your solution. I've just used variant for the case when `0` is valid input (I know OP operates with dates `Insert Date` but..for somebody who going to use it with numerics)

Comment: whoops missed the +1. added now.

Comment: I've tried to input 0 without your new improvements and it works like cancel so I don't mind that much, thank you very much though.

Answer (score 2):

something like this (I have included today's date as the default choice)

```
Dim lngCnt As Long
lngCnt = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Insert Date", Default:=Format(Now(), "dd-mmm-yy"), Type:=1)
If lngCnt = 0 Then
'user cancelled
Else
Sheets("Start").Range("B1").Value = lngCnt
End If
```

Comment: Thanks mate but not very useful in this case, as the date is going to be last day of previous month and not always. Only the first time of the month that's opens the excel I need the user to set new date. Next times I want him to bypass it with cancel. It's little more complicate that I can describe now but thank you for your effort though.

Comment: @Xaratsarhs you can always remove the default, or chnage it to the last day of prior month. It was provided as an example. The cancel check holds though.