# Date Picker in Excel 2010 without Microsoft Date and Time Picker

Tags: date, excel, time, picker, vba

I'm using Ms office 2010 and I don't have Microsoft Date and Time Picker. without the date and time picker can I use the Date and Time dialog box using vba?

Please me...

thanks in advance.

Comment: for datepicker check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012206/formatting-mm-dd-yyyy-dates-in-textbox-in-vba/12013961#12013961

Answer (score 0):

You need to get a copy of the actual DateTimePicker ActiveX Control.
Microsoft Date and Time Picker V 6.0
MSCOMCT2.OCX

Once you have it, follow these instructions. It doesn't come installed with 64-bit Office.

Step 1:
Copy MSCOMCT2.OCX into: C:\Windows\SysWOW64

Step 2: 
Run Command Prompt - Run As Administrator

Step 3:
in cmd (with the space, not the quotes) 
"regsvr32 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\MSCOMCT2.OCX"

Comment: I get the error 0x8002801c, are you familiar with this one? Do you know what is wrong?