# Calendar - custom made

Tags: vba, date

A came across this very useful [custom made calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012206/formatting-mm-dd-yyyy-dates-in-textbox-in-vba/12013961#12013961). One of the comments was : "Great! Useful Tool!!!"

I modified to save the picked date in a date variable, so I wouldn't have to reinterpret the date from text when I used it. In module, added: `Private dPickedDate as Date`. In each day command button changed to:

```
dPickedDate = DateSerial(
    Val(Format(CommandButton45.Caption, "YYYY")), _
    Val(Format(CommandButton45.Caption, "MM")), _
    CommandButton1.Caption) 
TextBox1.Text = Format(dPickedDate, "DD-MMM-YYYY")
```

**My Question:**

I'm not sure where/how to include the "Private dPickedDate as Date" Despite various attempts I can't get it to work...

Comment: maybe you can better explain what you are trying to achieve. That quoted comment is unclear

Comment: I want to run my code, open the  calender [userform] for the user to make his selection and then use the selection as variable in my code by allocating it to various other cells.

Comment: `Range("A1") = TextBox1.Value` doesn't do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I am not able to download the userform right now to check the code. But as I understand the comment, you should write

```
Private dPickedDate as Date
```

at the top of the UserForm1 module outside of any function.