# VBA Excel 2010 Microsoft Month View Control

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use the Microsoft month view control in Excel. How do I check if the user has picked a particular date using if statements?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend not to use monthview control. You may use [this alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012206/formatting-mm-dd-yyyy-dates-in-textbox-in-vba/12013961#12013961)

If you still want to use the monthview control then see [this](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/How-to-use-MonthView-5e8b32be)

The `MonthView1` controls return a string value which can be accessed by `MonthView1.Value`

And once you have the string value, you can convert that to a date value by using `CDate()`

For example

```
CDate(MonthView1.Value)
```

Now it is easy for you to use an if condition to do a direct date comparison.