# Date changing to USA Format from userform

Tags: vba, date, excel

I have a userform which requires date input and up until today hasn't caused an issue (Used for the last 2 weeks).

When the date is input it posts the information to a staging sheet that is visible on a printable page.

The format that originally worked was -

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = TextBox4.Value
```

But with the date now being 03/11/2014 it is switching this round to 11/03/2014.

I then tried to change this code to format it as a date e.g.

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Format(TextBox4.Value, "DD/MM/YYYY")
```

But again the date showed as 11/03/2014.

Does anyone have a solution to this date format error?

Thanks
Al

Comment: [Interesting read](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012206/formatting-mm-dd-yyyy-dates-in-textbox-in-vba/12013961#12013961)

Answer (score 1):

I found my dates worked correctly by using `CDate()`

```
With ActiveCell
    .Value = CDate(TextBox4.Text)
End With
```

Then it respects whatever my sheet formatting is. Attempting to format using code (i.e. `.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"`)  just wasn't making any difference.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do to avoid any problem with date formatting is:

```
With ActiveCell
    .Value = TextBox4.Text
    .NumberFormat = "DD/MM/YYYY"
End With
```

Like this you make the shown value into the cell independent from how it is inserted by the user, as long as it's a date-time value.

P.s. I have arbitrarily removed your `.FormulaR1C1` since you are inserting a value, not a formula, so there's no point to insert your textbox value into the formula property of the active cell.

Comment: I have tried this and for some reason it is still giving the same date error. @Matteo

Comment: Your code contains reference to `ActiveCell`, which means the currently selected cell. Are you sure you're not expecting your code to change a cell which is not the active one? I have tried this code and it works, cannot figure out why it shouldn't with you. Make sure also that you're not still using the `.FormulaR1C1` but rather the cell `.Value`.

Comment: I am activating the cell I require just before this runs - 'Range("M2").Select' @Matteo

Comment: Ok @AlanTreanor, last attempt. Can you re-try the code I have edited? I have changed from `textbox4.Value` to `textbox4.Text`, since the second property is the current content while the first might be stored differently (if it doesn't work, consider posting some more code running after the `.NumberFormat` change.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't working still I then tried using date 13/11/2014 and this worked but then 04/11/2014 showed as 11/04/2014. This is strange that it is changing the format.@matteo

Comment: Try `.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"` it might be the CAPS in the format