# Using the output of a custom calendar form

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012206/formatting-mm-dd-yyyy-dates-in-textbox-in-vba) userform to get a date but I do not know how to set it to display today as the default (always 18/08/2012) and I do not know how to actually get it to pass the selected date to the current sub.

I couldn't find the blog that was mentioned online.

```
Sub Macro1()
    UserForm1.TextBox1.Text = Date
    UserForm1.Show
    ActiveCell.Value = UserForm1.TextBox1.Value
End Sub
```

I'm trying to use the above code to test it.

Comment: Please provide the link or the code for the `UserForm`.

Comment: Wrote a solution for you. You can have a go at it or you can simply check the customize stuff posted by Trevor in the same link you got. Haven't tested it so it's up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `GenerateCal` Sub add this two(2) lines at the bottom.
These lines of code will initialize the values of the said controls.

```
CommandButton45.Caption = Format(.Range("A1").Value, "mmm - yyyy")
TextBox1.Text = DateSerial(Val(Format(CommandButton45.Caption, "YYYY")), _
    Val(Format(CommandButton45.Caption, "MM")), 1)
```

Then change this line:

```
.Range("a1").Value = Application.Text(dt, "mmmm yyyy")
```

to this line:

```
.Range("a1").Value = Application.Text(StartDay, "mmmm yyyy")
```

`dt` is of type string so it will generate a different result.

I also believe that being explicit is always better so I suggest you add this declarations on top of `GenerateCal` Sub.

```
Dim StartDay As Date, FinalDay As Date
Dim DayOfWeek As Integer, CurYear As Integer, CurMonth As Integer, x As Integer
Dim Cell As Range
Dim RowCell As Long, ColCell As Long
```

The next problem is the deletion of the temporary sheet generated by the `UserForm_Initialize` Sub. It seems you cannot delete a non-visible sheet (I'm using XL2013, I'm not sure if it is true to other versions). So you need to change it a bit like:

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
'    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    With ws
        .Visible = xlSheetVisible
        .Delete
    End With
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
'    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Notice that I removed the *OERN* and *OEG0* because I don't think there is a need for that.

Finally, to clean it all up, you'll need to clear the manually entered caption for `CommandButton45` and `TextBox1` in the properties window. Once you've incorporated all the changes correctly, you should get the correct date in your `Userform1`.

**Additional:**

You are accessing the value of `TextBox1` correctly. But I'd suggest to edit this code if you want to pass is somewhere.

```
'~~> Ok Button
Private Sub CommandButton53_Click()
    MsgBox TextBox1.Text
End Sub
```

**Sample:**

```
Private Sub CommandButton53_Click()
    ActiveCell.Value = TextBox1.Value
End Sub
```