# Set date format as dd-mmm-yyyy in activex textbox VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

Is there a way to set date format as `dd-mmm-yyyy` in ActiveX TextBox?

I'm using the code below to separate the quote but there is one error while user is putting month., i.e. 31-May-1993 but sometimes user is putting 31-may-2015.

Because of that unable to fetch the data through server...

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    If TextBox1.TextLength = 2 Or TextBox1.TextLength = 6 Then
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + "-"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you using Textbox to accept dates? You may want to see [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012206/formatting-mm-dd-yyyy-dates-in-textbox-in-vba/12013961#12013961)

Comment: @SiddharthRout... i checked ur post but the problem is m unable to download the that form...

Comment: Why what error message do you get?

Comment: Whenver i open that link it shows something went wrong.. or Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage

Comment: It opens up for me. Use a different browser...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can I suggest you take a different approach with this and do something like (Note this is untested and not final code just a few suggestions for how you could handle this):

```
Private Sub Textbox1_LostFocus()
  Dim Da as Date
  Da = CDate(Textbox1.Text)
  Textbox1.Text = Format(Da, "dd-mmm-yyyy")
End Sub
```

This will:

- Take whatever text is entered when the user clicks outside of the active box (LostFocus instead of running every key press)
- Convert the value to a Date
- Put back into the Textbox in the format that you require (dd-mmm-yyyy)

You could then add error handling in this so that if vba can't convert it to a date it could report to the user that they have entered an incorrect value and to correct it before proceeding.

I'm also not advocating that this is best practice but a way that the OP could get his method to work.