# Unable to open Additional Controls in the Toolbox

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I want to make a userform in Excel 2013, Visual Basic options.

I made a userform, but when I try to add adiitional controls to the toolbox, nothing happens.

I need to add date and time picker into the userform.

[image]

When I right click on the Toolbox, and select additional controls nothing happens. Please suggest something. Thank you.

Comment: 32bit or 64bit Office?

Comment: 64 bit Windows 8.1 running 32 bit Office 2013

Comment: Date and Time Picker controls are not Office controls. They are VB6 Controls. You may want to use [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012206/formatting-mm-dd-yyyy-dates-in-textbox-in-vba/12013961#12013961) alternative?

Comment: Good suggestion. @SiddharthRout