# MonthView multiselect Start and End date into cells

Tags: excel, vba, controls, userform

I'm creating a userform, part of which includes a MonthView control set up with the multiselect option enabled. I'm trying to get the start date and end date that the users select into two different cells on the worksheet (let's say A1 and B1 for example). From what I've looked up I understand that you can get the start/end date using SelStart and SelEnd, but I'm unsure of how to do this or how this works. I can get it to put in the first date selected by using something like this:

```
Private Sub MonthView1_DateClick(ByVal DateClicked As Date)
   On Error Resume Next
   Range("A1") = DateClicked
   Unload Me
End Sub
```

But that doesn't include the last date.

A workaround would be to have two separate MonthView controls programmed like the one above to put the two dates in separately, but I'd much rather use this drag to select functionality if possible.

Comment: See this article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa733656(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: Also see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012206/formatting-mm-dd-yyyy-dates-in-textbox-in-vba/12013961#12013961

Comment: I would advise against using "On Error Resume Next".  It can mask errors and cause a lot of problems.