# Run Excel VBA Datepicker on specific cells

Tags: excel, vba, datepicker

I'm using a Datepicker solution presented here [Formatting MM/DD/YYYY dates in textbox in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012206/formatting-mm-dd-yyyy-dates-in-textbox-in-vba/12013961#answer-26111741)

I can run it from a `Sub`, but is it possible to run it from clicking on specific cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick` event on your worksheet and only fire the code when a specific cell (or cells) are double-clicked.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

If Target.Address = "$C$2" Then UserForm1.Show `change to desired cell address and the name of your userform

End Sub
```

*this code should be placed in the `Worksheet` module*

Here is the documentation for the events https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn301178.aspx

Comment: Where do I enable the event?

Comment: just place the code in the `Worksheet` module for the sheet you want it to work with (as opposed to a standard module). then, double click on the desire cell and it will fire.

Comment: Thanks, I was placing it on "ThisBook" (I translated it because my office is Portuguese EsteLivro), I changed it and it works

Comment: I added the documentation for the events on your answer, so It becomes more complete for those like me who didn't know about them :)