# How to get date clicked on monthview to my textbox on userform?

Tags: vba, excel, calendar

```
Private Sub MonthView1_DateClick(ByVal DateClicked As Date)
Txt_Prod_Loc_Date.Value = MonthView1.Value
Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub FrmCalendar_Initialize()
Unload Me
End Sub
```

I also tried Txt_Prod_Loc_Date.Value= DateClicked. But I see a " runtime error 424, object required

Thanks

Comment: I don't have a `MonthView` control in my Excel. So, I can't be sure. Yet, your above code suggests that the variable `DateClicked` might contain the indicated date. Alternatively, I'd check the `.Value` of the control. Maybe the date is stored there `MonthView1.Value`?

Comment: When I hover my mouse at  DateClicked or MonthView1.Value in debug mode. I see the clicked date on the calendar. But, the value is not getting stored to my textbox. I taught when you do [textbox].Value= MonthView1.Value, the date should get stored to textbox. But, I don't see that happening.

Comment: BTW, even i did not have monthview in my tool box.  I right clicked on tool box and got into additional control to select Microsoft MonthViewControl.

Comment: BTW, I wouldn't recommend using the MonthView Control :). You may want to see [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012206/formatting-mm-dd-yyyy-dates-in-textbox-in-vba/12013961#12013961)

Comment: Thanks Siddarth.  Useful one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use both; `MonthView1.Value` or `DateClicked`. The problem is not because of that :)

BTW why do you have `Unload Me` in `FrmCalendar_Initialize()`? That would give you a `Run Time Error 91. Object Variable or With block variable Not set`

You are getting `Runtime error 424, object required` because it could not find the `Txt_Prod_Loc_Date` control on your userform.

If that control is in the worksheet then use it like this

```
Private Sub MonthView1_DateClick(ByVal DateClicked As Date)
    Sheet1.TextBox1.Value = MonthView1.Value
End Sub
```

If that control is in some other form (say `Userform1`) then use it like this

```
Private Sub MonthView1_DateClick(ByVal DateClicked As Date)
    UserForm1.Txt_Prod_Loc_Date.Value = MonthView1.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Siddharth Rout for your response. I had the textbox on a different User form. So with syntax like in your second option, the problem is solved.