# VBA - ActiveX - Open Datepicker by clicking on a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, vba

Good afternoon,

I'm using an ActiveXControl to choose a date on calendar. I would like to call this calendar by double cliking on a cell.

I'm able to do the action by clicking on a cell, but I can't find a way to show my calendar.

**My code :**
The problem is located Where the * is

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim Date_Debut, Date_Fin As String

Date_Debut = "$C$35"
Date_Fin = "$C$36"

Char_cellule_click = target.Address

Select Case Char_cellule_click

     Case Date_Debut
     Range("$B$35").Select
*    Call Externe_Picker_Start_CallbackKeyDown

     Case Date_Fin
     Range("$B$36").Select
     Form2.Show

End Select

End Sub
```

The only thing I can do so far is to show the activeXControl by doing :

```
     Case Date_Debut
     Range("$B$35").Select
     Externe_Picker_Start.Visible = True
```

What I would like is an action that simulates the click on the down Arrow of my activeXcontrol to show the calendar. Is it possible?

[image]

I hope I'm being clear. Let me know if not.

Thankis in advance for your help.

Best regards,

Jean

Comment: `If you are planning to distribute or share your workbook with other users then using the ActiveXControl is a bad idea. Consider using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012206/formatting-mm-dd-yyyy-dates-in-textbox-in-vba/12013961#12013961)

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. I just laoded the form. It is very slow on my computer. it takes a while to load and then like 3 to 5 seconds to change months. Considering it starts from Jan 2000, it's gonna take a while to get a date in 2017!
Plus, there is a one day difference between the weekdays in your calendar. (NB: Maybe this is linked to my French evrsion of Excel. Weekdays start from Monday, not Sunday).
I'm not gonna share this file. Unless the form can work in a faster way, I prefer to use an ActiveXControl. Any idea? See you

Comment: There are other answers in that post as well... :) Check them out. if you are still not happy then let me know and I will install the ocx to test it for you

Comment: Thanks Siddharth Rout, I'll try those during this w-e and will let you know :)

Comment: Once I needed a calendar control, the ActiveX one was really disappointing, so I built custom one, I can share if you want...