# Is there a way to create a date/time picker in a userform using VBA that will work on both windows and mac versions of excel?

Tags: vba, macos, excel, userform

I would love to be able to use the date picker that already exists, but it doesn't exist on the mac version, and this spreadsheet will be accessed by both windows and mac machines.

Comment: I don't think there is `Datepicker` in Excel. You can create one though, [try one of the methods outlined in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012206/formatting-mm-dd-yyyy-dates-in-textbox-in-vba). I even posted an answer there too.

Comment: @L42 This is pretty much what I am looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a userform that acts as a DateTime Picker that will function on both Windows and Macintosh.

The most noticeable issue will be related to **the difference in screen resolution** between the two platforms. On the Mac, it’s `96 dpi`, where each dot represents a **pixel**. In Windows, screen resolution is `72 dpi` (dots per inch) and each dot represents a **point**, while *pixels* are still **96 per inch**.

Confusing the issue is that **VBA in Windows uses points as the measurement unit** for designing UserForms, while **VBA on the Mac uses pixels**. The result is that without applying any correction, ***UserForms that come out just right in Windows are only 75% as large on the Mac***...

A solution can be to add a procedure that re-sizes the userform accordingly, depending on which system is currently calling the procedure, something like:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  #If Mac Then
    ResizeUserForm Me
  #End If
End Sub
```

---

### More info:

- More information & sample workbook at [the source](https://peltiertech.com/userforms-for-mac-and-windows/).
- Ron de Bruin : [Date Picker Add-in for Excel for the Mac](https://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/addins/datepicker.htm) with sample.