# European Date format in Userform

Tags: excel, vba, date, userform

I have a Userform that populates Textboxes with dates from a worksheet. The idea is to be able to edit the dates and save them back to the worksheet. The problem is the dates show up in American format, not European. I understand that I need to use code to force the date to show as European. So I have tried using this code

```
Dim LValue As String

LValue = Format(Date, "dd/mm/YYYY")
```

I then have a function to populate the form, where I want the correct date format to show

```
Sub PopulateForm()
            Me.Location.Value = rngFound(1, 0).Value
            Me.ID.Value = rngFound(1, 1).Value
            Me.FirstName.Value = rngFound(1, 2).Value
            Me.LastName.Value = rngFound(1, 3).Value
            Me.Grade = rngFound(1, 4).Value
            Me.ARLFam = rngFound(1, 8).Value
            Me.ARLEvac = rngFound(1, 11).Value
            Me.HRDFam = rngFound(1, 16).Value
            Me.HRDEvac = rngFound(1, 19).Value
            Me.CRDFam = rngFound(1, 24).Value
            Me.CRDEvac = rngFound(1, 27).Value
            Me.RSQFam = rngFound(1, 32).Value
            Me.RSQEvac = rngFound(1, 35).Value
            Me.COVFam = rngFound(1, 40).Value
            Me.COVEvac = rngFound(1, 43).Value
            Me.LSQFam = rngFound(1, 48).Value
            Me.LSQEvac = rngFound(1, 51).Value
            Me.HPCFam = rngFound(1, 56).Value
            Me.HPCTrackFam = rngFound(1, 63).Value
            Me.HPCEvac = rngFound(1, 59).Value
            Me.KNBFam = rngFound(1, 67).Value
            Me.KNBEvac = rngFound(1, 70).Value
            
End Sub
```

I haven't figured out where to place **LValue** in the sub routine for it to change the dates to the correct format. Am I on the right track? Or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Next, when I have changed the dates and save the changes to the worksheet, I encounter a new problem. The cells the dates go into are set up as dates, and other cells have formulas working off the information provided by the date cells. When I save the dates from the Userform, they show up in the correct cells, but all the other cells reading from the date cell now have the **#Value** error showing. This is the code used to save the new dates to the worksheet.

```
Private Sub EnterButton_Click()
Dim LR As Long
Dim replace As Long
Dim response As Long
Dim LValue As String

LValue = Format(Date, "dd/mm/YYYY")
If Me.ID.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "You have not entered an ID."
    Me.ID.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If

FindRecord (Val(Me.ID))
    If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
       replace = MsgBox("This record already exists in this Database." & vbNewLine _
       & "Replace?", vbYesNo)
       If replace = vbYes Then
            LR = rngFound.Row
       Else
            ClearForm
            Me.ID.SetFocus
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Else
        LR = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End If
            
    With ws
          .Cells(LR, 1).Value = Me.Location
          .Cells(LR, 2).Value = Val(Me.ID)
          .Cells(LR, 3).Value = Me.FirstName
          .Cells(LR, 4).Value = Me.LastName
          .Cells(LR, 5).Value = Me.Grade
          .Cells(LR, 9).Value = Me.ARLFam
          .Cells(LR, 12).Value = Me.ARLEvac
          .Cells(LR, 17).Value = Me.HRDFam
          .Cells(LR, 20).Value = Me.HRDEvac
          .Cells(LR, 25).Value = Me.CRDFam
          .Cells(LR, 28).Value = Me.CRDEvac
          .Cells(LR, 33).Value = Me.RSQFam
          .Cells(LR, 36).Value = Me.RSQEvac
          .Cells(LR, 41).Value = Me.COVFam
          .Cells(LR, 44).Value = Me.COVEvac
          .Cells(LR, 49).Value = Me.LSQFam
          .Cells(LR, 52).Value = Me.LSQEvac
          .Cells(LR, 57).Value = Me.HPCFam
          .Cells(LR, 64).Value = Me.HPCTrackFam
          .Cells(LR, 60).Value = Me.HPCEvac
          .Cells(LR, 68).Value = Me.KNBFam
          .Cells(LR, 71).Value = Me.KNBEvac
    End With
    
            If replace = vbYes Then
                MsgBox "The existing record on " & ws.Name & " row# " & rngFound.Row & " was overwitten"
            Else
                MsgBox "The record was written to " & ws.Name & " row# " & LR
            End If
            
          response = MsgBox("Do you want to enter another record?", _
              vbYesNo)

          If response = vbYes Then
              ClearForm
              Me.ID.SetFocus
          Else
              Unload Me
          End If
End Sub
```

Is it because the date has been saved as text instead of a date? If so, how do I get it to save as a European date?

Comment: dates are numbers, so if you save them as text, that may explain the error on formulas. Also, formating the cell as `dd/mm/yyyy` should help instead of doing it in a variable.

Comment: @Foxfire And Burns And Burns Thank you for the quick reply. The cells are formatted as _Dates_. What I am not sure about is what is being transferred from the userform to the cells, is it text, numbers or dates? And how do I use VBA to get it to transfer to the cells as _Dates_?

Comment: Formatting a cell as Date doesn't make them a Date.

Comment: @FunThomas - Now I am worried I have completely missed something here. I have _right-clicked_ the cell, selected _Format Cells_, then chose the _Numbers_ tab. Selected _Date_ and chose the style I wanted from the box to the right. Is that what you are referring to? Or is it something different?

Comment: If you write "Hello World" into a cell that is formatted as date, the content of the cell is a string, not a date. If you write "ABC" into a cell and afterwards format this cell as date, it's still a string. *Formatting* tells Excel how it should *display* your data. If you write a date into a cell and format it as "General", it will display the date as number (as dates are in fact numbers)

Comment: I tried to change the cells to _General_ and as you stated, numbers appear. The problem  is they do not show as recognisable dates which defeats the purpose of what these cells are supposed to display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following assumes that you have real dates in Excel (you can prove this for example by formatting a cell containing a date as `General`: It should display a number).

> Background: dates are stored internally as numbers, the integer part
> gives the `Date`-part, counting the number of days starting from 1.
> January 1900. The fraction part is representing the time, 1/3 would be
> 8am (a third of the day)

A textbox in VBA contains always a String. When you want to write a date into the textbox and use code like `tbStartDate = ActiveSheet.Cells("B2")` and `B2` contains a date, you are asking VBA to convert the date into a string. VBA will do so, but it has it's own rules for that and so you end up with a string that looks like an US date. Basically, you should always avoid that VBA does an automatic conversion for you. Instead, use a function for that: `Format` it the right function to convert a Date or a number into a string, you use it already correctly in the first 2 statements. To write the date into the textbox, you now write

```
tbStartDate = Format(ActiveSheet.Cells("B2"), "dd/mm/YYYY")
```

---

Now comes the tricky part: The user may change the date and you want to write it back to the cell. Again, you shouldn't let Excel do the conversion implicitly. The problem is that with a normal text box you cannot prevent that the user enters rubbish stuff (you might read [Formatting MM/DD/YYYY dates in textbox in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012206/formatting-mm-dd-yyyy-dates-in-textbox-in-vba)).

But let's assume your user enters the date in the "correct" form: How do you convert a string into a date?

You often see the answer to use `CDate` that converts a string into a date, respecting the locale setting of the system. Fine, as long as all users have the same settings. But if you might have a user coming with a Laptop freshly imported from the US or that comes from any other part of the world, you have the same problem again: VBA will convert the date with wrong assumptions (eg changing the day- and month part).

Therefore I usually use a small custom function that splits the string and use the parts as parameters into another VBA function `DateSerial`. It will return 0 (=1.1.1900) if the input is complete nonsense, but doesn't check all invalid possibilities. A 13 as input is happily accepted (`DateSerial`, btw, accepts this also).

```
Function StrToDate(s As String) As Date
    ' Assumes input as dd/mm/yyyy or dd.mm.yyyy
    Dim dateParts() As String
    dateParts = Split(Replace(s, ".", "/"), "/")    ' Will work with "." and "/"
    If UBound(dateParts) <> 2 Then Exit Function
    
    Dim yyyy As Long, mm As Long, dd As Long
    dd = Val(dateParts(0))
    mm = Val(dateParts(1))
    yyyy = Val(dateParts(2))
    If dd = 0 Or mm = 0 Or yyyy = 0 Then Exit Function
    
    StrToDate = DateSerial(yyyy, mm, dd)
End Function
```

Now, writing the input back to the cell could be like

```
dim d as Date
d = StrToDate(tbStartdate)
if d > 0 then ActiveSheet.cells(B2) = d
```

Comment: I have a Function with the following `Function FindRecord(ID)
    Set ws = Worksheets("Data Input")
    With ws.Columns
        Set rngFound = .Find(What:=ID, After:=.Cells(1), LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole, _
                                SearchDirection:=xlNext)
    End With
End Function`, then the populate function uses `rngFound ` to find the cells to populate the Text boxes in the UserForm. Your `tbStartDate = Format(ActiveSheet.Cells("B2"), "dd/mm/YYYY")` code, should it replace `rngFound(1, 8).Value`, or be placed somewhere else?

Comment: If `rngFound(1, 8)` it the cell tha contains the date you want to display, just use it instead of `ActiveSheet.Cells(B2)` I used it in my example

Comment: Thank you for your help so far. I am nearly there, just have a slight problem with your code `d = StrToDate(tbStartdate)`. If I leave it as it is I get the error "Variable not defined" and `tbStartdate` is highlighted. I tried replacing `tbStartdate` with `rngFound`, but then I get the error "ByRef argument type Mismatch". I think that I need to reference about 17 different variables as I have now got the form to populate correctly using this code `Me.ARLFam = Format(rngFound(1, 8).Value, "dd/mm/YYYY")` I suspect I should be replacing `tbStartdate` with `ARLFam`. Just not sure how to do it.

Comment: The Variable `ARLFam` is just one of 17 variables that will all have to be included in the loop somehow.

Comment: I used `tbStartdate` as example of a Textbox, replace it with the textbox name of your form - if your code lives within a Form, you should use the keyword Me (as you do already), so just try `Me.ARLFam = Format(rngFound(1, 8).Value, "dd/mm/YYYY")`. Do the same for all pairs textBox/ExcelCell that contain a date

Comment: I did that for the PopulateForm part, and that is working perfectly. I am trying to utilise your `Function StrToDate(s As String) As Date` code for when the data is placed back into their cells. This is where I am having the problem. I was trying to work out how to fit `d = StrToDate(tbStartdate)
if d > 0 then ActiveSheet.cells(B2) = d` into the 17 lines I have at present, which currently consists of `If Not Me.ARLEvac = "" Then .Cells(LR, 12).Value = Me.ARLEvac`.

Comment: I take it "d" is supposed to check the Function `StrToDate` to make sure the date is coded correctly before using the code I have to enter it back to the worksheet in the correct cells, so how do I fit "d" into the code I already have?

Comment: Use `.Cells(LR, 12).Value = d`

Comment: I am having trouble trying to work out how to get my section `Private Sub EnterButton_Click()` to work when I add in your  code `dim d as Date
d = StrToDate(tbStartdate)`. How do I get it to go to the Function `StrToDate(s As String) As Date` ?  I am getting a compile error "Variable not defined" and highlights `tbStartdate`.

Comment: I already wrote: *I used `tbStartdate` as example of a Textbox, replace it with the textbox name of your form*. I don't know what else I could explain to you

Comment: I think I finally understand what to do. I need to replace `d = StrToDate(tbStartdate)` with `d = StrToDate(ARLFam)` and then repeat the process the the next 16 variables?

Comment: I am struggling with getting your `Function StrToDate(s As String) As Date` sub routine to run within my `Private Sub EnterButton_Click() routine. I get errors "Variable not defined" if I try using `StrToDate`. Or Compile Error "Expected:List Separator if I try `Function StrToDate(s As String)`. Just tried `StrToDate (Val(Me.dateParts))` to see if I could make it work on my own. Got another Compile Error, this time it was "Method or data member not found" & `dateParts` was highlighted. What I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

you surely can change the current forat into an european one and here is some examples of how you can uses it :

Sub dates_et_heures()

```
'Now renvoie la date et l'heure en cours (07.02.2018 09:09:02)
date_test = Now()

'Renvoie : 07.02.18
Range("A1") = Format(date_test, "dd.mm.yy")

'Renvoie : mardi 7 février 2018
Range("A2") = Format(date_test, "dddd d mmmm yyyy")

'Renvoie : Mardi 7 Février 2018
Range("A3") = WorksheetFunction.Proper(Format(date_test, "dddd d mmmm yyyy"))

'Renvoie : mar. 07
Range("A4") = Format(date_test, "ddd dd")

'Renvoie : MAR 07
Range("A5") = "'" & Replace(UCase(Format(date_test, "ddd dd")), ".", "")

'Renvoie : FÉVRIER 2018
Range("A6") = UCase(Format(date_test, "mmmm yyyy"))

'Renvoie : 07.02.2018 09:09
Range("A7") = Format(date_test, "dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm")

'Renvoie : Le 7 février à 9h09'02''
Range("A8") = Format(date_test, "Le d mmmm à h\hmm'ss''")

'Renvoie : 9H09
Range("A9") = Format(date_test, "h\Hmm")
```

End Sub

I don't have the answer for the second part but i hope this could help too

Comment: Assuming that the cells contain a *Date*, you shouldn't write a *String* to them.

Comment: @FunThomas What should `LValue` bet set as, if not set as a _String_ for it to work as a _Date_?

Comment: @Ian Martin: When you write the data into the Textboxes, you write a String, that's fine. I was commenting this answer which is writing strings into Excel cells

Comment: @A.Amel - Thank you for the code. I am not sure how I am supposed to add one of them into the code I have already set up. As you can see, the date columns are placed specifically within the worksheet, and I need to be able to populate the Userform with the dates in European Format ("dd/mm/YYYY"), then once edited, to replace them into the correct cells on the worksheet.