# Date & Time Picker Inside a form with Excel 365

Tags: excel, vba

I have been searching and searching for an easy way to incorporate a date and time picker to insert into my form and cannot find an easy way of doing it.
I am a very amatuer coder that use VBA to automate my business world.

Is there anyone that can help with I thin should be something built into the forms controls to add a date and time picker into my form below instead of the user typing it in and making mistakes?

I also posted this on MRrExcel forum https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/date-time-picker-inside-a-form-with-excel-365.1229560/#post-6017212

[image]

Comment: Since VBA hasn't changed that much since then (even with the arrival of Excel 365, you should be able to find what you are looking for here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012206/formatting-mm-dd-yyyy-dates-in-textbox-in-vba

Comment: Yes I was able to use the date solution from that post but still don't have an answer for the time

Comment: How about [this](https://www.pk-anexcelexpert.com/time-picker-and-date-time-picker-control-in-vba/)?